# What is the angle of Incidence of wing of Airbus A320?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing, airbus-a320

What is the **Angle of Incidence/ Mounting Angle** of the wing of AIRBUS A320?

Comment: I vaguely recall it's around 5° at root to -0.5° at tip. The information is not particularly useful without the wing profile, which Airbus keeps to itself, and nothing is referenced to it; the stall angle of attack is referenced to the body axis.

Comment: @JanHudec General Aviation airplanes have about 6 deg. AOI. Isn't 5 deg. too much for commercial jets? Some websites suggest 1.5-2 deg. AOI but I don't know about the authenticity of this info.

Comment: I didn't say 5°, I said 5° at root to -0.5° at the tip. All swept wings are quite significantly twisted, otherwise they'd stall tip-first, which would be really, really nasty.

Answer (score 2):

The A320 wing is a complex design with no clear mention of chord or angle of incidence, as it is not topical to the operation of the aircraft. The wing is swept back, has variable symmetry from root to tip , as some say twisted. This info is not shared by Airbus.